# Raspberry Pi 2 Audio vs Video Clash

Tags: pi-2, audio, hdmi

So, I'm having an interesting issue. Those of you who have seen me around know that I don't usually use a GUI of any sort with my Pi. However, I recently got another one and decided to make an entertainment center out of it. I heard Kodi now has a plug-in for Google Play Music, and I've got some old VHS movies that I digitized and would like to stream to my TV. Now here's my issue: If I set the HDMI drive to 2 so that audio works, the video output is squeezed into this awful rectangle with a TON of empty space on the sides. If I change it around so that the video actually fills the screen of my TV, I can't get audio. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please be a little more descriptive as which sides have tons of space? Can you give me an approximate aspect ratio or resolution? Or even better a photo of your TV before and after?

Comment: It's just the left and ride sides. It's like it only displays in 4:3 on a 16:9 display.